# How to identify mobile devices like desktops?

Tags: javascript, php

I have reference the https://panopticlick.eff.org/ to help me identify computers hashing the plugins. But this does not work with mobile devices, android, iphone etc.

How can I identify mobile devices in a successful way, not by IP or user-agent?

I would like to use JavaScript for this.

Comment: You are asking about fingerprinting...

Comment: The problem is mobile devices are basically uniform. You will not get details like desktop browsers. Another framework https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintJS

Answer (score 0):

Panopticlick is more to prove that your browser information can be used to uniquely identify you on a website, if the website operator is so inclined.

Have a look at the Mobile Detect PHP class: http://mobiledetect.net/

Comment: THE OP is not trying detect the device type.

Comment: Sorry but I forgot to say that I need a JavaScript solution. But I find your link really good, thanks.

Comment: @Fataoulas: You should remove the `php` tag from your question then.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to detect the device, `navigator.userAgent` is the key.

```
if ( /Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent)){
    //your browser is on Android
}
```

or

```
if ( /iPhone/i.test(navigator.userAgent)){
    //your browser is on iPhone
}
```

Some other words you can test are: webOS,iPad,iPod,BlackBerry,IEMobile,Opera Mini. Here you can find the complete list. [**See**](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Mobile%20Browserlist/)

Another solution is use a javascript library, like [jQuery Browser plugin](https://github.com/gabceb/jquery-browser-plugin) (this depends of jQuery). or use some of this:

- https://github.com/kaimallea/isMobile
- https://github.com/PoeHaH/devicedetector

**UPDATE**
Libraries like [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com) has better feature detection than browser sniffing technique (my first proposed solution).

Comment: `navigator.userAgent` is **not** the way. It is often spoofed by browsers' 'imitation' mode, to fool websites **like this** into thinking it's something else.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention this. See my update. I think modernizr is a better choice.